# tune expensive spark query with group by clause

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run below query in spark sql and it is taking hours to execute and then failing with out of memory error

Is there a way to tune the query or rewrite in a better way?

my business logic require sum and count so i need to do a group by in query. any better way to achieve this?

table1 has 160+ billion records

table2 has 100+ million records

table1 is partition by date1

```
    select b.a1,
          ,date1
         ,count(distinct(a.e)) 
        ,sum(b1)
    FROM
    (SELECT
            a,
            ,b
            ,e
            ,date1
            ,sum(c*d) as b1    
    from  table1
    where a='xyz'
           and b=11111
           and d IN (15 parameters here in in clause)
           and date1 >= '2014-01-01'
           GROUP BY a
           ,b
           ,e
           ) a  
    INNER JOIN
          table2 b
    ON a.a=b.a
    group by b.a1,
    date1
```

Comment: try increasing the spark sql partition number. The default is 200. You may want to set it to 1000 or more depending upon your data. spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 2000

Comment: Also, you could try and re-partition your data to a higher number.

Comment: i currently have 1000 as partition number. i can increase it more but i dont see that resolving my issue.

Comment: i had run into the same issue. It did not speed up the process much but did solve my OOM error.